# How does real time communication over the internet work?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, real-time, iot

I'm researching and trying to building a RC car that can be controlled by the internet. I've started looking into how communication over the web works, but I seem to be going nowhere. My goal for the project is straight forward:

- The RC car has an on-board camera and 4g wifi router that enables communication (driving commands, video streaming) over the internet. A Raspberry Pi will serve as the on-board computer.
- I will be able to control the car with my PC even across the globe, as long as I'm connected.
- I want to preferably do as much by myself as possible without relying too much on other people's code.

So here are my questions:

- How does an application communicate over the internet? What is the interface between the application's logic (e.g pressing "w" to go forward), and transmitting/receiving that command over the internet?
- How is video data stream handled?

I've looked into WebRTC and WebSockets for communication, but they are aimed at providing real time communication to web browsers and mobile, not something like a raspberry pi, and I'm still in the blind as for exactly *what* technology should I use, and in general the overview and architecture of real time communication.

All I've achieved so far was an app that sends text messages between devices through a server on my network, with very primitive reading/writing using java Socket.

In short, what does messenger/skype/zoom do in the background when you send a message or video call?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can basically use _any_ protocol to communicate with your robot. The biggest challenge will probably be getting around firewalls, but otherwise, that can be as simple as opening a TCP link using the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. You cannot do real-time control over Internet, period. There is absolutely no way to guarantee the delivery latency. Your control commands can arrive with a delay from milliseconds to seconds, or never. No way around it.

Now, you can still do a number of reasonable steps to absorb that unpredictable latency as much as possible and safe-guard your remote robot from the consequences of the unreliable communication.

For example, instead of sending the drive commands directly - as in, acceleration, deceleration, turn angle, etc., you can send a projected trajectory that is calculated from your drive commands locally on a model. Your RC car must be sufficiently smart to do some form of localisation - at the very least, wheel odometry, and with a good enough time sync between the sender and the RC car you'll be able to control the behaviour remotely without nasty consequences of drive commands executed at an unpredictable delay.

You can add a heart-beat to your protocol, to monitor the quality of the communication line, and if hear-beat is delayed or missing, initiate emergency stop.

Also, don't bother with TCP, use UDP only and maintain your own sequence counter to monitor missing packets. Same applies to the telemetry stream, not just command channel.